# CSS Animation rotate3d not working in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, css-animations, css-transforms

I cannot get this animation to work in Safari 12 no matter what I try. I've tried vendor prefixes and all, but nothing works.

It works fine in Chrome. Anyone have any ideas?

```
<div class="spinners"></div>
```

This is the css:

```
@keyframes spinx {
  0% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 1, 360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 360deg);
  }
}
.spinners {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.spinners:before, .spinners:after {
  content: "";
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  border: 3px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -2rem 0 0 -2rem;
  display: block;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
}
.spinners:before {
  animation: spinx 2s infinite linear;
}
.spinners:after {
  border-color: blue;
  animation: spinx 4s infinite linear alternate;
}
```

Here's a demo:
https://codepen.io/Skinner927/pen/vVEdag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like both Safari and Firefox don't recognise the change between the two key frames. To solve this you can use an intermediate keyframe:

```
50% {
  transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 1, 180deg);
}
```

**Demo:**

```css
@keyframes spinx {
  0% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 1, 360deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 1, 180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }
}

.spinners {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.spinners:before,
.spinners:after {
  content: "";
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  border: 3px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -2rem 0 0 -2rem;
  display: block;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
}

.spinners:before {
  animation: spinx 2s infinite linear;
}

.spinners:after {
  border-color: blue;
  animation: spinx 4s infinite linear alternate;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="spinners"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much. I've been banging my head against my desk all day.

Comment: Thanks, this solved it!