# Why won't this 3d css animation work on mobile?

Tags: css, css-animations, transform

I have this 3d rotating text css animation working on chrome desktop, but it won't work on mobile. I tried adding webkit prefixes but nothing will get it to work on iphone. Any obvious reasons why?

https://codepen.io/warpigs666/pen/bGqQbzL

```
@keyframes turn {
  from { transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0); }
  to { transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 360deg); }
}

.container {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  perspective: 1000px;
  margin: 100px;
}

.cube {
  position: relative;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: turn 3s linear infinite;
}

.face {
  height: 2rem;
  background: white;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  transition: transform 500ms;
}

.top {
  transform: translateY(-1rem) rotateX(90deg);
}
.front {
  transform: translateZ(1rem);
}
.bottom {
  transform: translateY(1rem) rotateX(-90deg);
}
.back {
  transform: translateZ(-1rem) rotateX(180deg);
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  .cube {
    animation: none;
    transform: rotate3d(1, 1, 0, 45deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but I passed your CSS through [autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) and it may have helped? https://codepen.io/sforsberg/pen/vYxQYGZ don't have an iphone to test. You likely need to include `-webkit-` prefixes for all your animations.

Comment: Thanks, I already did that, if you click on the codepen link above it has the webkit prefixes, but no it still doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: This one was tricky! But a fun challenge. As I stated in my answer, it appears to be a general Safari issue, not mobile-specific. Anyway, hope my answer helps you. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your bug in both Mobile Safari on iOS and desktop Safari on my Mac, so the bug appears to have at least been related to Safari in general, not necessarily mobile-specific. Safari apparently does not like rotate3d transform animations with only 2 keyframes.

The fix boils down to adding an intermediate keyframe to the `@keyframes` CSS (see `50%`):

```css
@keyframes turn {
  0% {
    transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 0deg);
  }

  50% {
    transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 180deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 360deg);
  }
}
```

Here's an updated Codepen with the fix in action:

https://codepen.io/maqam7/pen/OJpaypZ

Note that I removed most of the prefixed rules while debugging, but also because they're unnecessary in newer versions of Safari (except `-webkit-backface-visibility` apparently). Up to you if you want to add them back in. Note that I also removed the transition styles on the `.face` class since they weren't doing anything.

I don't have access to an android phone, so I can't verify this works there. However, I can verify the above fix works in the latest (as of this writing) desktop Chrome (Mac), desktop Firefox (Mac), desktop Safari (Mac) as well as Mobile Safari on iOS.

---

Props to this Stack Overflow answer for providing the solution once I realized the problem was with Safari in general:

[CSS Animation rotate3d not working in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52571632/css-animation-rotate3d-not-working-in-safari#answer-52571777)

Comment: Side rant.... more evidence that Safari is the new IE IMO. :/ All the work I have to do nowadays to make websites cross-browser seems to be to get things working in Safari...

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!! Yes I totally agree Safari is the new IE. The more I learn about coding and try to build websites it becomes overwhelmingly obvious. It is so irritating that these companies can’t come to an agreement for the good of the industry and their customers.

Comment: Not sure this is worth your time, but if you happen to know... any thoughts on how I could turn this cube into an octagon. I've been working on it all day but nothing is making sense.

Comment: Glad I could help. It's sad that Safari is like the new IE because it gave the world webkit which was the basis for Chromium. Apple once was the poster child for standards compliance. Back in the day browser compatibility issues were so much worse than they are now. Now if it works in Chrome it works in Edge and Opera. Then you just have to worry about Firefox and Safari.

Comment: Don't have time to help expand your code unfortunately, but have a look at this link. Note that the last example lets you choose `n` faces and either horizontal or vertical orientation. Best of luck! https://3dtransforms.desandro.com/carousel

Comment: Thanks! This is what I am working through now, I appreciate it.